# error in android, Proguard.cfg (System can not find the file specified.)

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, proguard, android-proguard

How can I solve this problem shown in the image?
../tools/lib/proguard.cfg (System can not find the file specified)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting that problem is because newer versions of the Android SDK no longer have a ProGuard configuration file and instead rely on the Android Gradle plugin (Android Studio) to provide the relevant ProGuard configuration.

Google has officially dropped support for the Eclipse-based Android Development Tools (ADT) plugin, as mentioned in their [official announcement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html):

> The Eclipse ADT plugin is no longer supported per our announcement. Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate your projects to Android Studio as soon as possible. For more information on transitioning to Android Studio, see Migrate to Android Studio from Eclipse.

In order to be able to create new Android projects, you should migrate to Android studio using the [migration steps](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html) that Google provided.